# Eventbrige X-Ray config via Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-xray, aws-event-bridge

I see Eventbrdge has X-Ray support now which is great -

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-aws-x-ray-tracing-with-amazon-eventbridge/

But the example is via the CLI - does this feature have Cloudformation support yet ? As can't find any docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its **not related to CloudFormation**. [This works](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-aws-x-ray-tracing-with-amazon-eventbridge/) by wrapping your `putEvents` calls to Event Bridge.

> o enable tracing, you don’t need to change the event structure to add the trace header. Instead, you **wrap the AWS SDK client** in a call to AWSXRay.captureAWSClient and grant IAM permissions to allow tracing.

So you have to **modify your application** to use that feature.